# change display order of components between mobile/desktop layout

Tags: angular, components, responsive

I wonder how to display a different order of components depending on whether I am in mobile or desktop format

For example, if I have in mobile :

```
<compo-A></compo-A>
<compo-B></compo-B>
```

Is it possible to have in desktop ?

```
<compo-B></compo-B>
<compo-A></compo-A>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive this using [flex order properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) (example below uses [FlexLayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) for Angular but you can do the same using vanilla Flexbox)

```html
<div fxLayout="row">
  <compo-A fxFlex fxFlexOrder.gt-md="2"></compo-A>
  <compo-B fxFlex fxFlexOrder.gt-md="1"></compo-B>
</div>
```